# Make Image Full Width of Browser on SquareSpace

Tags: html, css, image, squarespace

I'm building myself a website on SquareSpace and having a bit of trouble with the layout. I've built a few sites before so understand the concept of CSS, and how it's applied to divs etc...

So, I want the page to have full width images (edge to edge in the browser) interspersed with text and graphics.

The banner image and footer image look **good, as you can see the image is edge to edge...**

[image]

The problem is with any additional images I try to add (SS makes you add them inside 'image block' objects), currently it looks like this **which is bad, and not edge to edge, shown here with red arrows...**

[image]

I have spent hours googling about, and testing various solutions and nothing works. I also spent the last 30 mins with SS support and they suggested making a 'gallery page' which **you can't add text to** so that's totally pointless!

I tried to identify the CSS ID and apply CSS to the image, **that didn't work either**:

[image]
[image]

Can anyone help?

current CSS not working:

```
.sqs-block.image-block { padding: 0 !important }

body {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Cheers
John

Comment: Without code is difficult to help. Maybe the issue are containers, or some padding, margin, etc.

Comment: Sure, I understand, I guess with SS you don't have access to the underlying code, it's WYSIWYG, and you can inject CSS. No matter what CSS I inject I can't seem to get the lower image edge to edge!

Comment: You already try negative margins?, this is not elegant, but if you dont have other way, possible work.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, have you an example css snippet I can try?

Comment: Can be position: relative, margin: 0 -20px. If this dont work descart my comments.

Comment: Good idea, doesn't work properly on SS though! thanks anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78723/discussion-between-woodstock-and-lmgonzalves).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a programmatic solution to this hideous problem.
However, I was able to figure out a way to manipulate a SS 'index' style page to achieve the effect I was looking for.